# Foreign Character showing Question Mark Diamonds

Tags: channel-entries, sort, title, low-alphabet

I have a problem, I have romainian character into the titles, but this code :

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="filme" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="off" limit="1000"}
<?php
$letter = strtoupper(mb_substr('{title}', 0, 1));
if ($temp != $letter) {
    echo "<a href='$letter'>".$letter."</a>";
    $temp = $letter;
}
?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Shows me on ș ț ă î something like these :�
What should I do that the output of php to come well and make my sorting method work ?
I want to build an Alphabet ..

Comment: What charset have you specified in your templates?

Comment: Hey @Jeremy I did specifiy in templates UTF-8 also in config.php . but no luck at all :((

Comment: did you try mb_substr('{title}', 0, 1, 'UTF-8') ?

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="filme" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="off" limit="1000"}
<?php
mb_internal_encoding ("utf-8");
$letter = mb_strtoupper((mb_substr('{title}', 0, 1)));
if (!in_array($letter, $temp)) {
    echo "<a href='$letter'>".$letter."</a>";
    $temp[] = $letter;
}
?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Tried that one and worked out ! the only problem now is i get multiple repetition of letters like: ( . 1 3 4 A B C D E F G H I Î I Î I Î I Î I Î I Î I J K L M N O P Q R S Ş S Ş S Ş S Ş S Ş S T Ţ T U V W - where do the repeat comes from ? what is wrong in my code ? Cheers

Comment: why do you think that this is repeated letters? I see different letters - S != Ş. Did you try to make  A-Z lists ? You can try - http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet. Also you can try to replace {title} with {url_title}. Or you can try to add letter in array and then check cond with in_array() function. In this case you will keep this lang. specific letters but remove duplications.

Comment: I did try Low Alphabet, but it won't get me Romainian Foreign Characters like Ș and Ț, it will take ș as s and ț as t...

Comment: well, in case if you want to separate it - try version with in_array. I make update for my post.

Comment: Thank you For ANSWER, i have another one Here: I want when I click on a Letter  to go to a link where Only That letter titles to be, What should be the filthering code ? Like an alphabet..